# How to make a sum of all posts displayed in a loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, counter

I am trying to figure out a way to print the sum of all the posts displayed in a loop. For example:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) :

$total_count = 1;
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
echo $total_count;
endwhile;
endif;

?>
```

Returns: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Since there are 7 posts in my loop. However, I would like to make a sum of all those 1's in order to get 7 as the result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to increment your `total_count`, instead of just printing it every time.
You will add 1 for each post and then print the total value. Check php assignment operators for [`+=`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)

```
<?php if (have_posts()) :

$total_count = 0;
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
$total_count += 1;
endwhile;
echo $total_count;
endif;

?>
```

Also keep in mind your counter should always start at 0.